# My client.get() is returning None but works for another Entity earlier in the code

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to get an entity from the datastore which is saved correctly and I am getting another entity successfully the same way shown below.

```
    key = datastore_client.key('Ent', id)
    ent = datastore_client.get(key)
```

I am using a post method and getting the id using flask it is the correct id but I get `None` when I print this entity.

The entity that is saved has the column name `Name/ID` and then the row has the corresponding id received `id=1716127979992848259` why is this?

Comment: Simple mistake turns out my id was an int not a string newbies watch out :)

Comment: Hi @Conor, you may post your solution as an answer and accept it, that way it will be easily visible to other users that may encounter the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Conor comments, issue was solved by changing the `id` to String instead of Integer

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.